# What keyword should I use to indicate the compiler that I intend to use a pre-defined class from a library package

Tags: java

What is the keyword that we would use in order to indicate to the compiler that we intend to use a pre defined class from a library package?

Comment: `import package.*` or `import package.class`...make sure the library is within the compilers and runtime class path...

Answer (score 0):

there is no need, just make sure the jar is in the class path and you import the classes.  once you do that you can just use the external class.